# Как получить доступ к CardLayout из другого класса?

Tags: java, swing, gui

Здравствуйте, в общем суть вопроса такова. Есть два класса MainClass и SubClass в MainClasss иметься CardLayout и мне надо изменить панель из другого класса. Я делаю как то так. Ниже MainClass где создан CardLayout.По клику кнопки я переключаюсь на другую панель, тут все хорошо.

MainClass

```
panel = new JPanel();
frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
panel.setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));

JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
panel.add(panel_1, "111");

btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
btnNewButton.setBounds(0, 0, 89, 23);
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {             
        CardLayout cr  =  (CardLayout)panel.getLayout();
        cr.show(panel, "222");

    }
});
panel_1.setLayout(null);
panel_1.add(btnNewButton);
panel.add(qw.panel(),"222");
```

SubClass

```
public JPanel panel(){
    kk = new JPanel();      
    kk.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);
    kk.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    kk.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    JButton  but = new JButton("1111111");
    but.setBounds(0, 0, 70, 30);
    but.setBackground(Color.red);
    but.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            qqq = new q1();
            CardLayout cr  =  (CardLayout)qqq.panel.getLayout();
            System.out.println((CardLayout)qqq.panel.getLayout());
            cr.show(qqq.panel, "111");
        }
    });
    kk.add(but);    
    return kk;
}
```

Но при переходе с панели которая создана в SubClass на панель MainClass не срабатывает. Что я делаю не так? Будьте добры подскажите. Спасибо.